# easiest way to connect paypal to my own shopping kart

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart, paypal-sandbox

I was just wondering is paypal express checkout the easiest solution. I've built a php shopping cart using sessions, my shopping cart also looks after emailing the client and all I want is to put a paypal button on my site where the total amount of payment is sent with the user to paypal to checkout. Nothing more.

Can anyone suggest or link to a tutorial which does this... your help would be much appreciated and I will mark you up... thanks.

Comment: This question is inappropriate here; it asks for opinion and discussion ("What's best"), and is discussed specifically in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) concerning which questions not to ask here. Voting to close as "not constructive". You might want to review the FAQ for a reminder of what you should (and should not) ask here. Thanks. :)

Comment: all the kool kids spell cart with a k

Comment: Ooooh, has anyone made a Mortal Kombat themed shopping cart--er, excuse me, Kart?  "Choose your items..." And the button for processing a payment and finalizing the transaction can be labeled "FINISH IT!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal express is the cheapest & easiest solution, particularly if you want to store information in your database about whether or not the transaction was successful.

If all you need is button functionality, you can use the paypal api to generate dynamic buttons. Just see - https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/button-manager